How can a node.js application start automatically when launching an Ubuntu system on WSL?
I have in my Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS system (under WSL) a node.js application (which was installed through npm) and runs with the command "mynode run".
How can I automate this to run when I start the WSL (and the default user automatically logs in)?
I tried adding it to /etc/profile (with sudo -i), crontab -e with @reboot, init.d/ but it doesn't work with any of those (maybe Node is not loaded yet when these run?). I saw some comments on forever and upstart but these articles are from 2013-2015 and I don't know if they are still valid
I have very basic knowledge of unix, so please bare with me! Thanks

Adding the command mynode run to the end of ~/.profile should do the trick (where ~ represents your home directory).
This will run whenever the user with the updated .profile logs-in.
Look here for more details.

I tried this already and it didn’t work..
